# using media queries on classes

Tags: html, css, media-queries

i'm trying to apply media queries to my classes in my CSS-file but can't seem to figure it out. This is the code I have in my CSS-file and when inspecting the website I can see that the font-size coming from the media query is crossed over even though the window is the "correct" size. Why is that and what should I do to so the text adjusts to the query?

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
.title-header {font-size: 20px;}}
```

[image]

Comment: Both of your rules have the same specificity, so _order_ matters. And the line numbers clearly show that your media query rule is before the “general” one, so it just loses out here of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you ensure that you are calling the media query style after the .title-header block?

Because from your example, the media query block is on line 15 & .title-header is on line 28.

Css will apply the code that is down the file.